# MYSQL - Multiple and condition on different values on same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table name `results`

```
+----+------+------+--------+
| ID | USER | EXAM | RESULT |
+----+------+------+--------+
|  1 |   10 | ssc  | 4.2    |
|  2 |   10 | hsc  | 4.5    |
|  3 |   11 | ssc  | 4.0    |
|  4 |   11 | hsc  | 4.4    |
|  5 |   12 | ssc  | 5.0    |
|  6 |   12 | hsc  | 5.0    |
|  7 |   13 | ssc  | 3.0    |
|  8 |   13 | hsc  | 3.0    |
+----+------+------+--------+
```

My goal is to retrieve distinct users having a particular score. For example ssc result > 4.0 and hsc result > 4.2.

If I put something like this

```
select distinct user from results where 
( exam = 'ssc' and result > 4.0 ) 
and 
( exam = 'hsc' and result > 4.2 )
```

It will return empty as exam cannot equal to 'ssc' and 'hsc' at the same time. If I put or condition in the middle like this

```
select distinct user from results where 
( exam = 'ssc' and result > 4.0 ) 
or
( exam = 'hsc' and result > 4.2 )
```

It will include user 11 which is unexpected because our target is to filter the users having greater than 4.0 in ssc.

My expected output will be something like this

```
10
12
```

Is there any way we can do this?

Comment: what will be your output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I have added my expected output to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function in `HAVING` and check both conditions are established.

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   ID INT,
   `USER` INT,
   EXAM VARCHAR(50),
   RESULT FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,10,'ssc', 4.2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,10,'hsc', 4.5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,11,'ssc', 4.0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,11,'hsc', 4.4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5,12,'ssc', 5.0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6,12,'hsc', 5.0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (7,13,'ssc', 3.0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (8,13,'hsc', 3.0);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT USER  
FROM T 
GROUP BY USER 
HAVING 
    SUM(exam = 'ssc' and result > 4.0) = 1 
AND 
    SUM(exam = 'hsc' and result > 4.2) = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8c2d7/1/0)**:

```
| USER |
|------|
|   10 |
|   12 |
```

Answer (score 1):

one method using join

```
  select t1.* from 
(
select * from results where EXAM ='ssc' and RESULT>4.0
    ) t1
  join
(
    select * from  results where EXAM ='hsc' and RESULT>4.2
) as t2 on t1.USER=t2.USER
```

Comment: You solution is also works fine however D-Shih's answer is more clean and small. Thank you anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

use conditional aggregation for filter out

```
select user from tablename
group by user
having 
sum(case when exam='ssc' and result>4.0 then 2 when exam='hsc' and result>4.2 then 1 end)=3
```